# mT5 Model Only Returns <extra_id_0> Token When Generating Answers

Tags: python

I'm working with the mT5 model from the Hugging Face Transformers library for a question-answering chatbot project. Despite training the model on a diverse dataset of question-answer pairs, the model consistently returns the token <extra_id_0> as its response, regardless of the input question.
here's my code.

train.py - training model

```
import torch
from transformers import (
    MT5ForConditionalGeneration,
    T5Tokenizer,
    TrainingArguments,
    Trainer,
)
from datasets import DatasetDict, Dataset

model_name = "google/mt5-small"
tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = MT5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_name)

data = {
    "train": [
        {"input": "Pytanie: Jak się masz?", "output": "Odpowiedź: Dobrze, dziękuję."},
        {"input": "Pytanie: Kim jesteś?", "output": "Odpowiedź: Jestem chatbotem."},
        {"input": "Pytanie: Jaka jest pogoda?", "output": "Odpowiedź: Niestety, nie mogę sprawdzić aktualnej pogody."},
        {"input": "Pytanie: Opowiedz mi coś ciekawego.", "output": "Odpowiedź: Czy wiesz, że Oktawian August był pierwszym cesarzem Rzymu?"},
        {"input": "Pytanie: Jakie masz hobby?", "output": "Odpowiedź: Jako chatbot, spędzam czas na uczeniu się nowych rzeczy."},
        {"input": "Pytanie: Ile masz lat?", "output": "Odpowiedź: Jako program komputerowy, nie mam określonego wieku."},
        {"input": "Pytanie: Co lubisz jeść?", "output": "Odpowiedź: Jako chatbot, nie potrzebuję jedzenia."},
        {"input": "Pytanie: Jak mogę ci pomóc?", "output": "Odpowiedź: Możesz zadawać mi pytania, a ja postaram się na nie odpowiedzieć."},
        {"input": "Pytanie: Czy masz rodzinę?", "output": "Odpowiedź: Jako chatbot, nie mam rodziny w ludzkim znaczeniu tego słowa."},
        {"input": "Pytanie: Czym jest AI?", "output": "Odpowiedź: AI, czyli sztuczna inteligencja, to gałąź informatyki zajmująca się tworzeniem maszyn zdolnych do wykonywania zadań wymagających ludzkiej inteligencji."},
    ],
    "validation": [
        {
            "input": "Pytanie: Co to jest Python?",
            "output": "Odpowiedź: Python to wysokopoziomowy język programowania, znany ze swojej czytelności i elastyczności.",
        },
        {
            "input": "Pytanie: Dlaczego niebo jest niebieskie?",
            "output": "Odpowiedź: Niebo wydaje się niebieskie, ponieważ molekuły powietrza rozpraszają niebieskie światło słoneczne bardziej niż inne kolory.",
        },
        {
            "input": "Pytanie: Co to jest czarna dziura?",
            "output": "Odpowiedź: Czarna dziura to region w przestrzeni, gdzie grawitacja jest tak silna, że nic, nawet światło, nie może się z niej wydostać.",
        },
        {
            "input": "Pytanie: Czym jest fotosynteza?",
            "output": "Odpowiedź: Fotosynteza to proces, w którym rośliny, algi i niektóre bakterie przekształcają światło słoneczne na energię chemiczną.",
        },
        {
            "input": "Pytanie: Jak działa internet?",
            "output": "Odpowiedź: Internet działa poprzez połączenie milionów komputerów na całym świecie za pomocą sieci telekomunikacyjnych i satelitarnych.",
        },
    ],
}


def transform_data_format(data):
    transformed_data = {"input": [], "output": []}
    for item in data:
        transformed_data["input"].append(item["input"])
        transformed_data["output"].append(item["output"])
    return transformed_data

train_data_transformed = transform_data_format(data["train"])
val_data_transformed = transform_data_format(data["validation"])

train_dataset = Dataset.from_dict(train_data_transformed)
val_dataset = Dataset.from_dict(val_data_transformed)
dataset = DatasetDict({"train": train_dataset, "validation": val_dataset})

def tokenize_data(examples):
    model_inputs = tokenizer(examples["input"], padding="max_length", truncation=True, max_length=512)
    labels = tokenizer(examples["output"], padding="max_length", truncation=True, max_length=512)
    model_inputs["labels"] = labels["input_ids"]
    return model_inputs

tokenized_datasets = dataset.map(tokenize_data, batched=True)

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./results",
    num_train_epochs=3,
    per_device_train_batch_size=4,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=4,
    warmup_steps=500,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    logging_dir="./logs",
    save_strategy="epoch",
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_datasets["train"],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_datasets["validation"],
)

trainer.train()

model.save_pretrained("./results")
tokenizer.save_pretrained("./results")
```

here's chat.py - loading model and answering to user

```
from transformers import MT5ForConditionalGeneration, T5Tokenizer

model_checkpoint_path = "./results"

tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint_path)
model = MT5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint_path)


def generate_answer_seq2seq(question):
    formatted_question = f"translate Polish to Polish: {question}"

    input_ids = tokenizer.encode(formatted_question, return_tensors="pt")

    output_ids = model.generate(input_ids, max_length=50, num_beams=5, early_stopping=True)

    answer = tokenizer.decode(output_ids[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
    return answer


question_seq2seq = "Pytanie: Co robisz?"
print(generate_answer_seq2seq(question_seq2seq))
```

I was expecting my model to answer as I declared in data section.

- I've formatted my training and validation data as pairs of inputs and outputs, with questions prefixed with "Question:" and answers with "Answer:".
- The model has been trained using the Trainer API from Hugging Face, with a custom dataset created from a dictionary and loaded into a DatasetDict object.
- After training, when using the model to generate answers to new questions, it only returns the <extra_id_0> token, not a readable text answer.
- I've experimented with various generation parameters (max_length, num_beams, early_stopping, etc.) but still only receive the <extra_id_0> token as output.
- I've also tried to change formatted_question onto f"Pytanie: {question}", but it also gives me the same token as output.

I'm looking for guidance on troubleshooting this issue and any tips on optimizing the mT5 model for a question-answering chatbot application. Any advice or insights from those with experience in working with mT5 or similar models for text generation would be greatly appreciated.